# Winforms Devexpress application deployment

Tags: c#, winforms, dll, devexpress

I'm worikng on a `winforms` application which uses `DevExpress` controls.

It was fine on development computers but when i try to deploy the applicaiton on a customer computer it does not work because i guess it can't load `devexpress` dlls.

Even i make all the dll's on **properties->publish->application files** as include, it didn't work.

Then i installed `Devexpress` components on target computer and it started to work. How can i make the application work on customer computers without installing `devexpress component library`?

Comment: You **must** install DevExpress' **redist** (see [this document](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument3124) for details).

Comment: i installed it on development computer but do i also have to install it to every customer computer?

Comment: On development computer you install the full packet (library, design time support, examples and whatever else). In customer computer you install only redists (no design support, no code, no examples, no docs) according to your EULA. Start from the link I posted to understand which DLLs you have to redist. To **install** them is not just to copy somewhere (unless _somewhere_ is application folder), you'd better to put them in the GAC. Your setup builder should manage all these dependencies (or are you using a custom xcopy deploy?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You mentioned that you marked them in Properties -> Publish -> Application Files. For the most part, the files will be marked included, but there are some that might say "Prerequisite (Auto)" and you'll have to explicitly mark them as Include.  In the example screenshot below, you would have to change the DevExpress.SpellChecker from Prerequisite to Include:

[image]

You may also want to check the "Show all files" checkbox in that same dialog and see if there are any listed not explicitly marked as Excluded.

Finally, when your application fails on the client computer, the exception details should contain the name of the missing component and that should give you a big clue.

Answer (score 0):

In your DevExpress installation Folder is a Subfolder *Bin\Framework*. You have do deploy the dll you use in your Application with it.

Edit: you should also consider the comment of *Adriano*

Comment: I copied that folder completely to the target computer without installing DevExpress components but it didn't work. May be there is some registry things?

Comment: When you copy the dll to the place where your exe-file is then you don't need any registration. If you copie to a other place you have to extend win-path-variable (win searchpath).

Answer (score 0):

If you're just copying your application from the bin folder then just find the DevExpress dll's under "References" in your solution and change the property "CopyLocal" to "true".